# Graphics card with Clarkdale

Tags: intel-graphics, intel-core-i3

I have finally decided, rather ordered Core i3 530 and ASUS P7H55M Pro. While they are on their way home, I was thinking that H55 chipset uses the Clarkdale's onboard IGP, but what if I add a graphics card?

Will IGP (processor's onboard graphics core) become useless?

Comment: The IGP is dual monitor capable however.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an external graphics card, the IGP will no longer be used.