# Motherboard gigabyte H55M switch graphic card

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have installed on my pc an nvidia geforce gt 430 graphic card and when I'm using ubuntu I'd like to switch and use the intel cpu integrated graphic card. Is it possibile to make this switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel H55 chipset disables the integrated graphics (electronically) when a graphics card is inserted into one of the PCIe slots.

The only way to enable the on-board graphics adapter is to physically remove the discrete graphics adapter.

More info: "[H55 chipset: why not simultaneous integrated + discrete graphics?](http://communities.intel.com/thread/15343)"

Also see:

- [Graphics card with Clarkdale](https://superuser.com/questions/190321/graphics-card-with-clarkdale)
- [multiple (3) monitors using intel iGPU + PCI-e graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/223931/multiple-3-monitors-using-intel-igpu-pci-e-external-video-card)